# why does this code (jquery each.) stops after 1st?

Tags: jquery

I have a div called notifications at the top of my site. 
I want to cycle through an array of text and show each value one after another inside that div every 30 seconds.

The below code I wrote doesn't work and I've tried several times to figure it out but nothing's worked.

```
var my_array = ["first text", "second text", "third text"];

jQuery.each(my_array, function(index, value) {
    jQuery('.notifications').replaceWith(value).delay(500);
});
```

Comment: `.delay()` pauses animations. `.replaceWith()` is not an animation.

Comment: that referenced post doesn't use each() to loop through an array... so thats not a valid reference to answer my question.

Comment: Did you research at all? There are [lots](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12450383/how-do-you-make-text-change-every-second) and [lots](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32445323/jquery-replace-text-every-2-seconds-with-words-from-an-array) of questions about doing what you need already

Comment: @Ryan The duplicate explains what's wrong with your code and gives alternative solutions to what you're trying to do. `.each()` isn't relevant to the problem.

Comment: even when I remove the delay part it still stops on the first one so I dont understand how the .each isn't part of the problem if its not looping through each element in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`delay()`](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) method is using for providing a delay in animation queue so you can't use it with [`replaceWith()`](https://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) method. Secondly the [`replaceWith()`](https://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)  will replace the entire element with a new element in the DOM tree so in the second iteration `jQuery('.notifications')` would select nothing since the element is already replaced.

To make it work use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) method and instead of replacing entire element just update the content of the element using [`text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/) method.

```js
var my_array = ["first text", "second text", "third text"];

// variable for counting
var i = 0;

// initialize interval and cache the return id
// to clear the interval later
var inter = setInterval(change, 500);
// call the function to execute initially
change();

function change() {
  // update the content
  jQuery('.notifications').text(my_array[i++]);
  // check count reache the length of array
  if (i == my_array.length)
  // if reached length of array then clear the interval
    clearInterval(inter);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="notifications"></span>
```